# i'm connecting my react with firebase and getting this error. Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

/*    im connecting my react with firebase and getting this error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
If i comment the (ReactReduxFirebaseProvider) it runs but still not working data isn't going into my firebase collection.
*/
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import {createStore,applyMiddleware,compose} from "redux";
    import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import thunk from "redux-thunk";
    import { getFirebase, ReactReduxFirebaseProvider } from "react-redux-firebase";
    import {
      getFirestore,
      reduxFirestore,
      createFirestoreInstance
    }
      from "redux-firestore";
    import fbConfig from "./config/fbConfig";
    import firebase from "firebase/app";
    
    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
        reduxFirestore(firebase,fbConfig)
      )
    );
    
    const config = {
      userProfile: "students",
      useFirestoreForProfile: true,
    };
    
    const rrfProps = {
      firebase,
      config,
      dispatch: store.dispatch,
      createFirestoreInstance,
    };
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
          <App />
        </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
    
    reportWebVitals();







// This is the APP Component code
import FeedbackForm from './components/feedback/FeedbackForm';
import StudentDetails from './components/feedback/StudentDetails';
import './sass/main.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import MoreDetailsForm from './components/feedback/MoreDetailsForm';
import ThankYou from './components/feedback/ThankYou';
import Dashboard from './components/admin/dashboard/Dashboard';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={StudentDetails}/>
        <Route exact path="/feedback" component={FeedbackForm} />
        <Route exact path="/moredetails" component={MoreDetailsForm} />
        <Route exact path="/thankyou" component={ThankYou} />
        <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
      </Switch>
   </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I could see this being a dependency issue. What version of `react` and `react-dom` are you on?

Comment: "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",

Comment: @Wasim Can you share the component code using hooks?

Comment: ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}> //here it fails and show mentioned error
      <App />
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

Comment: Hmm. How about `react-redux`? I would try reinstalling those three packages first. If that doesn't help, you are probably calling a hook from `react-redux-firebase` inside a class component when hooks can only be used in functional components.

Comment: "react-redux": "^7.2.2",

should reinstall these three packages??

Comment: i'm using functional component

Comment: @Wasim I was asking for the component code using any of the react hooks. Can you share your `App` component?

Comment: where i can paste the code ..the comment section not allowing me to do so..(sorry i'm new to the community)

Comment: @Wasim You can add it to the question.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan i have updated it. plz check

Comment: @Wasim Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Can you create a minimal, reproducible [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) example?

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan here is the CodeSandbox link :   https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-currying-m0kq8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Wasim How do I reproduce the issue?

Comment: You can check the index.js file if there any mistake in code. i'm not getting any output or error in the codebox as well

Comment: @Wasim The app loads fine for me. I'm able to see the student details form and upon submission, I'm redirected to the feedback page. I don't see any errors.

Comment: but in my pc i'm still getting the same error. how can i check if it is react version issue?